# Rendering templates in node.js app in order

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I want to create a node.js app, where I want to render multiple different pug templates in a specific order. E.g. after the user clicks a button on "template1", "template2" should be rendered. If the user presses a button on "template2", "template3" should be rendered...

At this point I have a simple app.post call (see below) to render "template2" after the button was clicked on "template1".

How would I go about rendering "template3" after "template2"? Do I have to include some kind of if block to check which template the user is currently on?

```
app.post('/', async function(req, res, next) {   
   res.render('template2')
});
```

Comment: Every template could have its own path, e.g., `app.post('/template2', async function(req, res, next) {res.render('template2')})`.

Comment: just make a route for each template, or use params, i.e `/template/:id`, but that would involve you validating req.params.id is a found template in your views  directory, which might be beyond your understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are confusing server side Javascript with client side html/script. If I understand your question, it should be:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.render("template");
app.get("/2", (req, res) => res.render("template2");
app.get("/3", (req, res) => res.render("template3");
```

And `template.pug`:

```
p 
  a(href="/2")
    button Next
```

In `template2.pug`:

```
p
  a(href="/3")
    button Next
```